# Access class methods by dynamical created string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In this example:

```
class Test {
  foo1: string = '';
  foo2: string = '';
  foo3: string = '';
  baz: number = 1234;
}

let bar = new Test();

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
  bar['foo' + i] = '42';
```

TypeScript gives me the error message `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Test'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Test'.`

What is the best way to get rid of this error message - and still keep the ability to use a dynamically created string to access the content of a class?

Comment: Even if you said `'foo' + i` was `keyof T` (or used a [template literal type](https://tsplay.dev/wgD6MN)) you're trying to assign `42` to a _string_ property.

Comment: bar['foo' + String(i)] should work

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it's a [mre] that doesn't have any unrelated issues like assigning `42` to `string` properties

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvqYnm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe and @ jcalz thank for the catch, you are completely right about this mistake. That's the curse of boiling the code down to create a minimal example :)

Comment: @jcalz yet that does the trick. Thanks! But why is the backtick solution for TypeScript acceptable and a normal addition isn't?

Comment: Because it was never implemented and would have catastrophic effects on compiler performance, as described in [ms/TS#51583](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51583) and [ms/TS#44905](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44905#issuecomment-875784954)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a dynamic key as a string where all members are numbers, you can use:

```
class Test {
  [key: string]: number;
}

let bar = new Test();

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  bar[`foo${i}`] = 42;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/smoosh-http-h8pzp3

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But it sadly doesn't work anymore when the class has other members that don't follow the signature `[key: string]: number`. I'll update the question to include that as well to be more precise.